# Having issues writing query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to write a query that will display the customer id, first name, last name, and return date. I need to figure out who was the last person who rented the movie. I know I need to pay close attention to the INVENTORY, FILM, RENTAL, and CUSTOMER tables. I'm just not sure how to write it.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    customer.customer_id, customer.first_name,
    customer.last_name, rental.customer_id, rental.return_date 
FROM
    customer, rental 
WHERE 
    customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
```

[This is the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AowrF.png)

[Tables and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73D9q.png)

Comment: Your model is not accessible

Comment: I don't see rental.return_date in the model you posted.

Comment: You have to provide a bit more detail. For e.g., whether you have time information anywhere ? Or is rental_id always an incrementing sequence? I am guessing once you manage to join the tables, then an order by the relevant column in descending order should do the job. This relevant column may be a time/date column or a sequence column. Please do consider supplying a bit more information.

Comment: I've added the tables and columns in question. Sorry I should've added those in my original post. There is time information within the rental table. Not sure if I'm more clear this time around.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say with the information you provided, but you could try this:

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, rental.customer_id, rental.return_date
FROM customer FULL JOIN rental
ON  customer.customer_id=rental.customer_id 
WHERE rental.return_date=(
    SELECT MAX(return_date)
    FROM rental
);
```

You can also use INNER, LEFT, OR RIGHT JOIN. What you pick depends on your models. [PostgreSQL Joins](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-joins/)

Comment: Wow this is great! I think I sort of have an idea of how I need to write the query. I basically need to find out which costumer rented a movie, so I would need to add TITLE from the RENTAL column... I think. Sorry if I'm not super clear, english is not my first language.